# Is there a way to delete a multer file after a certain amount of time?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have multer set up to store an image in a temp folder, send it to Imgur via a POST request, then the POST request deletes it from the folder via `fs.unlink('path')`. I'm worried that an unknown error or crash or something will occur, and a bunch of images will get stuck in the temp folder. I could set up a bunch of `fs.unlink`'s all over the place, but I'm wondering if there's a way to set up multer so that the file is deleted after x amount of time.

Here's what my multer setup looks like:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

// Init Upload Multer
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{fileSize: 20000000},
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
  //Do some function here?
}).single('myImage');
```

And here's the basic POST:

```
app.post('/upload-image', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        console.log('Error: No File Selected')
      } else {
        imgur
          .uploadFile(`./public/uploads/${req.file.filename}`)
          .then((json) => {

           //I do some stuff with the json and mongodb then:
           fs.unlink(`./public/uploads/${req.file.filename}`, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return
              }
              console.log('file deleted')
            })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err.message);
          });
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Any thoughts on making sure I don't get a bunch of extra images in the temp folder?

Comment: The straightforward way to do is to
1) Setup your filename with some prefix that indicates the time it was created
2) Have a scheduled/cron job that will check the temp folder, and remove file based on that prefix

Comment: @PK214 Do you know of any good tutorials on creating scheduled/cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller for deletePost...

```
exports.deletePost = async (req, res, next) => {
  const postId = req.params.postId;
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);

    if (!post) {
      const error = new Error("Could not find post.");
      error.statusCode = 404;
      throw error;
    }
    if (post.creator.toString() !== req.userId) {
      const error = new Error("Not authorized!");
      error.statusCode = 403;
      throw error;
    }
    // Check logged in user
    clearImage(post.imageUrl);
    await Post.findByIdAndRemove(postId);

    const user = await User.findById(req.userId);
    user.posts.pull(postId);
    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted post." });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

This is my `clearImage` Function...
Use this function in the Delete image Controller...

```
const clearImage = (filePath) => {
  filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", filePath);
  fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => console.log(err));
};
```